# Filtering a tuple with an integer_sequence

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

template <size_t... Indices, class F, class T>
auto map_filter_tuple(F f, T &t) {
    return make_tuple(f(std::get<Indices>(t))...);
}

int main()
{
    auto times2 = [](auto i) { return i * 2; };
    auto t = make_tuple(1, 2, 3, 4);
    auto t2 = map_filter_tuple<0, 1, 2>(times2, t);
}
```

This works but I am wondering how I could pass an integer_sequence to `map_filter_tuple`

```
auto t3 = map_filter_tuple<std::integer_sequence<size_t,0,1,2>>(times2,t);
```

I have looked at the source for `integer_sequence`and it doesn't expose the variadic template.

I guess I would have to use specialization? I am just not sure how I would approach it.

Comment: Note that `std::integer_sequence<std::size_t,0,1,2>` is equal to `std::index_sequence<0,1,2>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <std::size_t... Is, typename F, typename T>
auto map_filter_tuple(F f, T& t)
{
    return std::make_tuple(f(std::get<Is>(t))...);
}

template <std::size_t... Is, typename F, typename T>
auto map_filter_tuple(std::index_sequence<Is...>, F f, T& t)
{
    return std::make_tuple(f(std::get<Is>(t))...);
}

template <typename S, typename F, typename T>
auto map_filter_tuple(F&& f, T& t)
{
    return map_filter_tuple(S{}, std::forward<F>(f), t);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad142a08e47497b3)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is already there. You can pass in an index sequence to infer the indices :

```
template <size_t ...Indices, class F, class T>
auto map_filter_tuple(F f,T &t, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
{//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return make_tuple(f(std::get<Indices>(t))...);
}
```

The code is showcased in this <kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/685547512d579510)</kbd> where we only use a portion of the initial tuple. furthermore the `std::index_sequence<>` parameter is not named so it will be optmized away and only its type will be used.

Comment: *furthermore the parameter is not named so it will be optmized away* => Named or not does not matter; compilers (generally) see past syntax and operate on semantics.

Comment: @MatthieuM. unnamed means that it can't be used, apart from tach dispatching by value, so yes the compiler can optimize away non used arguments right ?

Comment: A name is syntactic. An unused value, whether named or not, has the same semantics... and the compiler reasons about semantics. The only value of not naming it is avoiding warnings complaining about an unused parameter (which is quite important, especially if like me you compile with `-Werror`).

Comment: So in the stack frame of the function there will be space created to accomodate this non used non named argument ?

Comment: In your case, given that there is no specific destructor, I would expect not. I would also expect the function to be inlined at the call site which kinda renders the whole idea of its own stack frame moot :)